# Extract abbreviation from string of the words longer than 3 letters by regex

Tags: python, regex, abbreviation

```py
string1 =  'Department of the Federal Treasury "IFTS No. 43"'
string2 =  'Federal Treasury Company "Light-8"'
```

I need to get the first capital letters of words longer than 3 characters that are before the opening quote, and also extract the quoted expression using a common pattern for 2 strings.

Final string should be:

- for `string1`: `'IFTS No. 43, DFT'`.
- for `string2`: `'Light-8, FTC'`.

I would like to get a common pattern for two lines for further use of this expression in DataFrame.

Comment: The word `Russia` appears nowhere in the first input string.  From where is it coming?

Comment: from a bank statement

Comment: Look into built in method str.split(). It will return a list of elements in your string and you can iterate through each one and apply logic desired.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try something like [`\"([^\"]+)\"|\b([A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/O3VBWP/1) [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 > quoted, group 2 > capital letters.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen,  Sorry, I didn't understand your question at first. Then I found an error in my assignment. I fixed it. But at the same time, I ended up solving it myself. This pattern fits right here r'(\w)\w{3,}|\"([^\"]+)\"'. The output needs a bit of work, but so far it suits me the best.

Comment: # My code:

import re

row = 'Federal Treasury Company "Light-8"'
pattern = r'(\w)\w{3,}|\"([^\"]+)\"'
matches = re.findall(pattern, row)
print('{}, {}'.format([match[1] for match in matches if match[1]][0], 
                      ''.join(map(str,[match[0] for match in matches if match[0]]))))

# output 'Light-8, FTC'

Comment: @broncaeux Have a look at [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY1NSwMxFEX3@RWXt0poHVrrSuhCkIKbbuzKyQijfdMJNB@8pGDB/z5mRChu77n3nnQtYwybaXI@RSkQVkr4xF/YQsiSbt8tdQtj6dt@6Pbp7q0zpFSumJ459VI8h4I4oIyMHR9Z@jMOwn2@yBWWXnaHV@xjg4eNJRvq1vflc@T5QbgZXDi6wqJ/pUtkM/tn2BItQdQpNUSBhwv4Wz4qwA3aNyeJl6TvjZkT1LvcrjsstrihCvic@VZY/Susqy6JC6X6s5mmHw).

Comment: @broncaeux You're welcome, glad that helped! :) I put it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
"([^"]+)"|\b[A-Z]
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/O3VBWP/2) (FYI read: [The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick))

It either matches the quoted parts and captures [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) double quotes `"`inside`"` to the *first* capturing group OR matches each capital letter at an initial [`\b` word boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) (start of word).

```
import re

regex = r"\"([^\"]+)\"|\b[A-Z]"

s = "Department of the Federal Treasury \"IFTS No. 43\"\n"

res = ["", ""]

for m in re.finditer(regex, s):
  if(m.group(1)):
    res[0] += m.group(1)
  else:
    res[1] += m.group(0)

print(res)
```

[Python demo at tio.run >](https://tio.run/##VY4xiwIxEIX7@RWPqTboLYpXCRbCIVxzjVa32YMVZzXgJmESQeH@@xptxHa@77038ZZPwS/G0Q0xaIYKkcpRrlhB2XLV/FluJ8byv90364/flolSgfwlsdM8iM8IPfJJsJGDaHfGTqVLF73B8vdmt8VPqPG5sGw9P8of6YZ5CuaWqA@KAc6X5bp3/uCyaPX8YIpklgS4vhrqo4ZLrObmeUGRUzNrMVnhhQqQc5KXMH8TZoYoqvO5tCczjnc)

```
['IFTS No. 43', 'DFT']
```